# How can I find a parameter's original variable name as a string at runtime?

Tags: c#, .net

I got in `Form_Load :`

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                this.Controls["txtPrix"+i].Enter += new EventHandler(DlgFacture_Enter);
            }
```

I got the event :

```
    void DlgFacture_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.setTextBoxPrixEnter((TextBox)sender);
    }
```

In that last event, I want to be able to print the `TextBox` root variable name (thus `txtPrix1` to `txtPrix10`) as a string, depending on which one calls the event.

How can that be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the Name property?

```
this.setTextBoxPrixEnter(((TextBox)sender).Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not easily.  What you're attempting to do is print the name of a reference to an object at runtime.  There can be many references to a given object so printing one in the abstract is not possible.

What you would have to do is wrap the Enter handler with a new method that captures the variable name and passes it along.

For example:

```
var name = "txtPrix"+i;
Controls[name].Enter += (sender,e) => DlgFacture_Enter(name, sender, e);

void DlgFacture_Enter(string name, object sender)
{
    this.setTextBoxPrixEnter((TextBox)sender);
}
```